# Print out only the bottom string

Tags: python

Given the values in Python Shell

```
1400 
670
4145
```

Is there a way for me to only print

> *4145*

For lists, I used the *slicing method* to select which string I wanted to use.

```
mylist = ["1400", "670", "4145"]
print(mylist[-1])
```

Would I have to transfer the values into a list in order for me to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand. When you type nothing but a number into the shell it prints it back out for you. So you are inputting `1400` seeing "1400" printed, inputting `670` seeing "670" printed, inputting `4145` and seeing "4145" printed? This seems to me that it is already only printing the 'bottom string', no?

Comment: @Reedinationer Yes, you are correct. That is the final given.

Comment: Well then I guess if you only want "4145" printed, that you should only input `4145` to the shell? I'm still not quite understanding the question I think...

Comment: It's not just you @Reedinationer. Jake: What do you mean about "transferring the values into a list". From where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `readline.get_current_history_length()` function to obtain the length of your current command-line history, and use the `readline.get_history_item()` function to obtain the command at a specific index:

```
>>> import readline
>>> 1400
1400
>>> 670
670
>>> 4145
4145
>>> mylist = [readline.get_history_item(i) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())]
>>> mylist
['mylist = [readline.get_history_item(i) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())]', 'import readline', '1400', '670', '4145']
>>> mylist[-1]
'4145'
>>>
```

Note that if you are on Windows then you need to install the `pyreadline` package in order to use the `readline` module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use `_`.

If you input those values, sending `_` and hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will return that last value:

[image]